# Как реализовать данную конструкцию ? Выбора ответа?

Tags: java, android

Есть правильный ответ, и есть 4 ВЬюШКи(наверное это кнопки?), при нажатии текст с кнопки сравнивается с правильным ответом и идет след.задание, но как сделать тогда так, чтобы правильный ответ был не на одной кнопке, а был и на другой кнопке? Чтобы пользователь не жал всегда на правую кнопку и получал правильный ответ?
Как правильно такое реализовать?
Проверка выбранного ответ с правильным ответом происходит с помощью equals.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В зависимости от кода что как происходит проверка непонятно, можно к примеру сравнивать надпись на кнопке с правильным ответам через equals ( если бы вы дополнили код как происходит проверка, был бы конкретный ответ а так способов очень много)

Comment: @Артем поправил.

Просто, не костыльно ли это 4 кнопки и так проверять?

Comment: Ну если проверка через  equals в чем проблема поменяйте кнопки местами? Костыльно для кого ? 1 строка кода (создайте массивы с ответами и правильными ответами засуньте их в цикл и проверяйте) через массивы меняйте вопрос и ответы

Comment: @Артем , как кнопки местам поменять?
Можете привести пример кода, того, что вы написали?

Comment: ну просто текст меняйте положение такоееже , лад щас пример накатаю

Comment: @Артем жду.....

Answer (score 1):

Раньше не пробовал писать подобное. но я бы написал так Пример:

```
         package com.example.amon.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String[] question = {"5-2", "5+3", "7-2", "7-2", "7-2"};
    String[] mAnswer = {"3","37","7", "7","3","8", "5","3","3","3","3","3", "5", "3","3","3","5"};
    String[] answer = {"3", "8", "5", "5", "5"};
    TextView quest,Answerq;
    Button one,two,three;
    int pos = 0;
    int prav_otvet = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        quest= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Answerq= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
         three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);

        quest.setText(question[0]);

        one.setText(mAnswer[0]);
        two.setText(mAnswer[1]);
        three.setText(mAnswer[2]);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        pos = pos+1;
            quest.setText(question[pos]);

            one.setText(mAnswer[pos+4]);
            two.setText(mAnswer[pos+3]);
            three.setText(mAnswer[pos+1]);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "ответ Неправильный ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        if (((Button) view).getText().toString().equals(answer[pos])){
            prav_otvet = prav_otvet + 1;
            Answerq.setText(String.valueOf(prav_otvet));
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "правильно ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }

    }
}
```

и разметка:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.amon.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="154dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Сколько будет ?"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Праильных ответов:"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: В mAnswer строке , меняешь числа местами  как хоч по 3 кнопки насчитай чтобы в одной из них был правильный ответ